# How to replace dates in text file with Powershell using regular expressions

Tags: regex, date, powershell, replace

I've done much searching on this and haven't worked out the answer, but I feel like I am close!

I have dates in a text file in the following format: `18/06/2012 23:00:43 (dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS)` which I want to convert to: `2012-18-06 23:00:43 (yyyy-dd-mm HH:MM:SS)` using Powershell.

To perform the conversion in a text editor using regular expressions I would do this:

```
Find: ([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)

Replace with: \3-\2-\1
```

So I have tried using this same logic in a the following Powershell script:

```
(Get-Content C:\script\test.txt) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)", "(\3-\2-\1)"} | 
Set-Content C:\script\test.txt
```

but that results in the following undesired change:

> \3-\2-\1 23:00:43

Can anybody help me nail this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have a date string in some variable ($date) then to reformat it easily in powershell: ***(Get-Date $date).ToString('yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss')***

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
(Get-Content C:\script\test.txt) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)", '$3-$2-$1'} | 
Set-Content C:\script\test.txt
```

Capturing group references are done with the `$` symbol, not a backslash. Also, to reference a captured group by number, [you must use single quotes around the replacement string](http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html); otherwise, PowerShell will interpret any `$` symbol as a reference to a previously defined variable, which in this case will result in the string `"--"` since no such variables exist.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but unfortunately I am still getting the result: \3-\2-\1 23:00:43 with this script. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AshBestos: Did you remember to save your script after copying this in? That's my first guess.

Comment: Aha, I was actually checking a file called text.txt in a different directory! Oops! Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The -replace operator supports the same replacement text placeholders as the Regex.Replace() function in .NET. [E.g. $& is the overall regex match, $1 is the text matched by the first capturing group, and ${name} is the text matched by the named group "name"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html).

Instead of `"(\3-\2-\1)"` use `'($3-$2-$1)'`

`'06/18/2012 23:00:43' -replace "(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)", '($3-$2-$1)'`

Answer (score 2):

try

```
Foreach-Object {$_-replace "([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)", '$3-$2-$1'}
```